# PTR record with multiple sending domains

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-bounces, ptr-record, srv-record

We have a set up with two dedicated IP addresses that send e-mails from multiple domains. As an example, the dedicated IP addresses are `192.0.2.1` and `192.0.2.2`, and the domains are `example.com`, `example.net` & `example.org`. Any IP address can send an email from any domain.

How would the PTR and SRV record set up need to look in this situation?

My understanding of PTR records is that there needs to be a 1:1 relationship between the sending IP address and the domain name that each email is being sent from. So we could set up PTR records that would establish `192.0.2.1` <-> `example.com`, however this does not help when `192.0.2.1` sends an email from `example.net` or when `192.0.2.2` send an example from `example.net`.

I apologise if my understanding is incorrect and am more than happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The SMTP server software probably has one *mailname* it uses in the `HELO` / `EHLO` commands and as the SMTP banner. It is recommended (not necessary) that it matches the reverse DNS `PTR` record, which MUST have a matching forward `A` record, as some receiving mail systems may treat mismatches between those two as an indicator of spam, increasing spam score. David Barr recommends matching `PTR` & `A` in his informational [RFC 1912, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912.html#section-2.1), and MxToolBox has these recommendations:

- [SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch)

  > Some receiving mail servers may use this as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system.  Most will not reject incoming mail solely on this basis.  We recommend that you contact your ISP and ask them to setup a reverse record (PTR) that matches the hostname of your mail server.
- [SMTP Banner Check](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check)

  > Some receiving mail servers may use a mismatched or masked banner as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system, but most will not reject incoming mail solely on this basis.
  >
  > If you do not have a PTR record, or your record does not match your hostname, we recommend that you contact your ISP and ask them to setup a reverse (PTR) record that matches the hostname of your mail server.

I would not recommend having the same hostname for both of these IP addresses, either, but simply use a single IP address with any hostname with a matching `HELO` hostname, `A` & `PTR`. That does not need to be any of the domains the server send mail from, nor a subdomain of one. It is perfectly fine to send, e.g.,

```
< 220 mail.example.org ESMTP
> HELO example.com
< 250 mail.example.org
> MAIL FROM:<user@example.net>
< 250 2.1.0 Ok
```

Here, the `example.net` and `mail.example.org` are recommended to have SPF records, as SPF is used both for `MAIL FROM` ([RFC 7208, 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208.html#section-2.4)) and `HELO` hostnames ([RFC 7208, 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208.html#section-2.3)). E.g.,

```
mail.example.com.  IN  A    192.0.2.1
mail.example.com.  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +a -all"
example.net.       IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +a:mail1.example.com -all"
```

or

```
mail.example.com.  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.1 -all"
example.net.       IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.1 -all"
```

If you add DMARC, you might want to use `~all` instead of `-all`. I won't write yet another full tutorial, as there is already, e.g., [The Ultimate SPF / DKIM / DMARC Best Practices 2024](https://www.uriports.com/blog/spf-dkim-dmarc-best-practices/) from Freddie Leeman.

Answer (score 1):

The PTR record doesn't necessarily need to match the domains sending mail through this IP, but should refer to the hostname of the mail server, which needs to resolve to the same IP.

The PTR records

```
1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR  mail1.example.com.
2.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR  mail2.example.com.
```

Matching records in `example.com`'s DNS:

```
mail1.example.com.  IN  A  192.0.2.1
mail2.example.com.  IN  A  192.0.2.2
```

The SPF record of each domain can then be modified to allow mail from this server, either by IP addreses, hostnames or an include from another domains SPF record.

```
example.com.  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.1 +ip4:192.0.2.2 -all"
example.net.  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 +a:mail1.example.com +a:mail2.example.com -all"
example.org.  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 include:example.com -all"
```